# ConditionalOnProperty create bean by nullable property

Tags: spring-boot

I set a property to null if an ENV variable is NOT set. Unfortunately, the `ConditionalOnProperty` check doesn't work and the bean is still created. How can I prevent this?

Unfortunately, I cannot change the conditional check. `my.property` is null

```
my.property=${MY_ENV:#{null}}
```

```java
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty("my.property")
public MyBean myBean() {
  return new MyBean();
}
```